# asp.net MVC how to modify one column only

Tags: asp.net

Hi I have this piece of code that works when updating data into db.
However i have 20 columns in my table. how can i make sure:
1) Only ACCOUNT_ID will be updated? (currently all 17 columns get overwritten into NULL after updating)
2) how to indicate in UI that only ACCOUNT_ID is editable? (eg greyed out)

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MovieApp.Models;



 namespace MovieApp.Controllers
    {
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private dtsdbEntities _db = new dtsdbEntities();
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_db.IPR_CompanyGen_200200501.ToList());
        }
    // GET: Home/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var CompanyToEdit = (from m in _db.IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 where 
(m.CompanyID.Equals(id.ToString())) select m);
        return View(CompanyToEdit);
    }

    // GET: Home/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 CompanyToEdit)
    {
        var OriginalCompany = (from m in _db.IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 where 
(m.CompanyID.Equals(CompanyToEdit.CompanyID.ToString())) select m.First());

        _db.Entry(OriginalCompany).CurrentValues.SetValues(CompanyToEdit).First();
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }





}

internal class MoviesDBEntities
{
}
```

}

Edit.cshtml

```
       @model MovieApp.Models.IPR_CompanyGen_200200501

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    }

    <h2>Edit</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>IPR_CompanyGen_200200501</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyID)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label 
    col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = 
   "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyName, "", new { @class = "text- 
    danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ACCOUNT_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label 
    col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ACCOUNT_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = 
   "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ACCOUNT_ID, "", new { @class = "text- 
    danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

Tried with Bind but still columns goes to NULL (take CompanyName , Address1 as example)

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CompanyID,CompanyName,Address1,Address2,Address3,City,StateProvinceCode,PostalCode,CountryCode,Region,PhoneNumber,URL,PrimaryCompanyType, DominantCompanyStyle,   DominantCompanyOrientation, Buy_side,   Sell_side,  Strategic,  EqPortfolioTurnover,    ReportedEquityAssets,   Status, LastModifiedDate,   ACCOUNT_ID, CRM_Comments")] IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 CompanyToEdit)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
        var OriginalCompany = (from m in _db.IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 where (m.CompanyID.Equals(CompanyToEdit.CompanyID.ToString())) select m).First();


        OriginalCompany.CompanyName = CompanyToEdit.CompanyName;
        OriginalCompany.Address1 = CompanyToEdit.Address1;


        _db.Entry(OriginalCompany).CurrentValues.SetValues(CompanyToEdit);

        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your problem with your code:

```
 OriginalCompany.CompanyName = CompanyToEdit.CompanyName;
 OriginalCompany.Address1 = CompanyToEdit.Address1;


 _db.Entry(OriginalCompany).CurrentValues.SetValues(CompanyToEdit);
```

You get the originalCompany from db assing new values to it and finally you edit the object which came as parameter which have all other properties null.

Replace it with this:

```
_db.Entry(OriginalCompany).CurrentValues.SetValues(OriginalCompany);
```

Answer (score 2):

On the values that should not be touched at all, in the `view`, on the `class="form-control"` add a `disabled` attribute. Like

`class="form-control" disabled`

Also to prevent the values from being set `NULL`, put a `Bind()` in the `[HttpPost]` part of the controller. Like so

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include ="Id,Account_Id,NextField,OtherField,etc.")] IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 CompanyToEdit)
```

Inside of the `[Bind("")]`, just put the column names that exist in the model. In the controller have `if(ModelState.IsValid)`

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var CompanyToEdit = (from m in _db.IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 where 
    (m.CompanyID.Equals(id.ToString())) select m);
    return View(CompanyToEdit);
}

// GET: Home/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="Id,Company_Id,Account_Id,Other_Properties")] IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 CompanyToEdit)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
          var OriginalCompany = (from m in _db.IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 where 
          (m.CompanyID.Equals(CompanyToEdit.CompanyID.ToString())) select m.First());

         OriginalCompany.CompanyName = CompanyToEdit.CompanyName;
         OriginalCompany.Company_ID = CompanyToEdit.Company_ID;
         OriginalCompany.WhatEverProperty = CompanyToEdit.WhatEverProperty;
         OriginalCompany.Account_ID = CompanyToEdit.Account_ID;
         //do this for every property and place a breakpoint to view every value


          _db.Entry(OriginalCompany).CurrentValues.SetValues(CompanyToEdit).First();
          _db.SaveChanges();

          return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: public ActionResult Edit([Bind(CompanyID, ACCOUNT_ID)] IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 CompanyToEdit) -- Do i need to keep the ""? i tried both but both got error @janzen

Comment: You need to keep every property from the model in the bind or it will set them to null, even the ones that are not being edited. `[Bind("Id,Account_Id,Company_Id,Other_Values")]`

Comment: If it doesnt work, then maybe there is a library that is missing. Also try adding in the body of the controller, put everything in a 
`if (ModelState.IsValid){
    //do everything
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

Comment: Sorry I forgot the `Include`, I know in asp.net core I dont need `Include` but other versions may.

Comment: do i need to keep the "" in bind? public ActionResult Edit([Bind(CompanyID, CompanyName, Address1, Address2, Address3, City, StateProvinceCode, PostalCode, CountryCode, Region, PhoneNumber, URL, PrimaryCompanyType, DominantCompanyStyle, DominantCompanyOrientation, Buy_side, Sell_side, Strategic, EqPortfolioTurnover, ReportedEquityAssets, Status, LastModifiedDate, ACCOUNT_ID, CRM_Comments)] IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 CompanyToEdit)

Comment: Also when you say 'include', where should it go?

Comment: when i use "", it says 'bind attribute does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments'; without "", error is bind attribute does not contain a constructor that takes 24 arguments

Comment: `Edit([Bind(Include="CompanyID,CompanyName,Address1,Address2,etc,etc")] IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 CompanyToEdit)`

Comment: public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include ="CompanyID, CompanyName, Address1, Address2, Address3, City, StateProvinceCode, PostalCode, CountryCode, Region, PhoneNumber, URL, PrimaryCompanyType, DominantCompanyStyle, DominantCompanyOrientation, Buy_side, Sell_side, Strategic, EqPortfolioTurnover, ReportedEquityAssets, Status, LastModifiedDate, ACCOUNT_ID, CRM_Comments")] IPR_CompanyGen_200200501 CompanyToEdit)

Comment: now after i updated ACCOUNT_ID, all the columns except for CompanyID, become null...

Comment: I'm not sure, I often add the bind attribute in my controllers, and unless I forget to add a property, they all stay the same except the value I edit. If I were you I add an instance of the model in the controller and debug it, that way it will show the exact values for each property, it will look something like this

Comment: Also, if there is an error, then delete the bind attribute but keep the object instance that I showed, and just debug, hover over error property and see its value

Comment: I tested out with 2 columns (CompanyName, and Address1). There was no error but They still become NULL . Debug also shows null in auto section

Comment: Good you got it!